# White line around <img> element in HTML

Tags: html, css

When i add a  element and reference what is supposed to be inside of it trough CSS a stupid white outline appears. Heres the code:

```
<div class="button"><img src="your-image-url.jpg"></div>

<style>
body {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 100px;
}

.button {
    padding: 0; /* Add this to remove padding /
    margin: 0; / Add this to remove margin */
}

img {
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
}
</style>
```

I have tried:

outline: none
border: none
box-shadow: none

nothing worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding an actual image inside the div makes the outline disappear. The white outline stays there only to remind you that there needs to be a image loaded, which either failed to load or is loading.

Comment: Yes, i solved the problem using the information you provided, i just preloaded a 256x256 transparent empty .png and the outline dissapeared. :)

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the `.button` class might have a `margin` because of a typo in the comment. Besides that, `<img>` are notorious for being `display:inline` and having a default margin in browsers. So try to set the image `display: block`

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 100px;
}

.button {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"><img src="https://picsum.photos/128"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that this white stripe is not contained in the image itself, because everything works as it should for me.

Comment: No it doesnt have, even when you paste the code here: 

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_editor

it has the same outline, you can try for yourself.

Comment: I just tried your code with this picture, on this site, there are no white lines...
https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/gradient-blue-abstract-background-smooth-dark-blue-with-black-vignette-studio_1258-68032.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.1.735520172.1711411200&semt=ais